Convergence of a series for a triangular array of random variables
Inspired by my previous post (in which I believe there is an error in the answer I gave) I am interested in the following:
Suppose $\{X_{n,i}\}$ is a triangular array of row-wise iid random variables in which$$
\mathbb{E}[nX_{n,\cdot}]\to\mu
$$where $\mu>0$.
Is this sufficient to conclude that $$
\sum_{i=1}^n X_{n,i}\xrightarrow{a.s.}\mu?
$$
If not, what additional hypothesis would one require to establish the result?
An application of the triangle inequality shows that it is sufficient to conclude that$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{n,i}-\mathbb{E}[X_{n,\cdot}])\xrightarrow{a.s.} 0.
$$
One may assume that $X_{n,i}$ is uniformly bounded by 1 and positive.
Update: If the absolute third central moment of $nX_{n,\cdot}$ is uniformly bounded above by $K$, then one has$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \big(X_{n,i}-\mathbb{E}[X_{n,\cdot}])\big)\right|>\varepsilon\right)\leq \frac{n\mathbb{E}[|X_{n,1}-\mathbb{E}[X_{n,\cdot}]|^3]}{\varepsilon^3}=\frac{n(1/n^3)\mathbb{E}[|nX_{n,1}-\mathbb{E}[nX_{n,\cdot}]|^3]}{\varepsilon^3}\leq\frac{K}{n^2\varepsilon^3},
$$which,  being summable, implies the almost sure convergence. Now the question might be, does the convergence $\mathbb{E}[nX_{n,\cdot}]\to\mu$ imply anything about the higher order absolute central moments of $Y_{n,i}:=nX_{n,i}$?

indicate the error in your previous answer please

In the previous post I am wary because the concentration inequality I derived works even when $\varepsilon=0$

I assume “row-wise” means the $i$ dimension? Also I think you may need to use fourth moments. How can third moments be used?

Information about first moments does not say anything about higher moments.

I see. I think I made a mistake in assuming that $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{I=1}^n X_i^3]=n\mathbb{E}[X_1^3].$ Ive seen the fourth moment trick you might be thinking of in the SLLN.
